# Encoding Issue?

Tags: php, encoding

I am having an issue with encoding (i think).

In my code I am getting the current directory using this php code:

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Which returns something like:

```
/Users/gprime/htdocs/loadrðt
```

But should return:

```
/Users/gprime/htdocs/loadr
```

I am guessing it has to do with encoding. That extra ðt that it appends should not be there. I tried to convert all files to UTF-8 which is for some reason causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: looks like its a buffer overflow. like the string isn't properly terminating.

Comment: Are you working on MacOS? Check the name of file for unprintabel chars, maybe simply recreate the file.

Comment: Please, post information that `echo __FILE__;` outputs. That will help us.

Comment: `var_dump(__FILE__)` even better!

Comment: __FILE__: /Users/gprime/htdocs/loadr/index.php
dirname(__FILE__): /Users/gprime/htdocs/loadr
realpath(dirname(__FILE__)): /Users/gprime/htdocs/loadr

Comment: The error for that is: Failed opening required '/Users/gprime/htdocs/loadrÈbt'

Comment: I think I solved it, I changed the charset in the php.ini to UTF-8, haven't had the error since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The php.ini default-charset had to be set to UTF-8. After I did this everything worked :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an encoding issue in the directory name, rather than the file content. Converting the file content to UTF-8 will not help - you need to rename the directory. Try renaming it to something random and then to loadr again.